# Django: Form set using SesionWizardView

Tags: django, forms, get, wizard, formset

I have question about Formsets in Django. I couldn't find answer on the internet.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/

I'm trying to make an example using this documentation, but I don't know how to change the default template.

I know that I should use `get_template_names()` in the `ContactWizard` class but I don't know what this method is supposed to look like.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `get_template_names()` should return the template name depending upon your logic (e.g. step, form etc).

E.g. Sample template returning different templates depending upon form for the step or step number etc.

```
 def get_template_names(self):
    if issubclass(self.get_form(str(self.steps.current)).__class__, BaseModelFormSet):
        return 'wz_formset_template.html' #depending upon form type
    else if self.steps.current == 2 :  #depending upon step
        return 'wz_step_2_template.html' 
    return 'wz_form_template.html'   #default template
```

Comment: Ok I understand but where should i write this method ? In forms.py in class ContactWizard(SessionWizardView) ?

Im new with forms in django ...

Comment: Yes, this is method of your wizard view class (where you have defined `done` method.)

Comment: Ok i undrestand but my urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^contact/$', ContactWizard.as_view([ContactForm1, ContactForm2])),
)
when i open this url (/contact/) i still have default view ... What im doing wrong ?

Comment: @Silwest can you update your question with relevant view, template code?

Comment: My code looks very bad ;/ Can you please show me some example of views.py ?

Comment: @Silwest Example would as straight forward as documented in django docs. Your problem might be due to some bug in your code, on which people on this site can help with.